# Is there any definition of such semi-bilinear?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, finite-fields

$K$ is a finite field which not equal to its base field $F_2$.

Let $f: V \rightarrow K$ be a function and $B(x,y)=f(x+y)+f(x)+f(y)$ such that $B(x+y,z)=B(x,z)+B(y,z)$ and $B(z,x+y)=B(z,x)+B(z,y)$ for every $x,y,z \in V$ (vector space over $K$) but $B(ax,y)$ is not necessary to equal to $aB(x,y)$ for every $a \in K$, same for $B(x,ay)$. Actually $B$ is linear over base field of $K$, but not linear over $K$.

Is there any such research area?

Example: $f(x)=Tr(x^9+x^5)$ where $Tr: F_{256} \rightarrow F_4$ is trace function.

Comment: Is it exactly [this situation](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semilinear_transformation), or not quite?

Comment: Thanks for this. I also did sth like that. I will add know an example.

Comment: While we're at it, the Hermitian inner product isn't really bilinear, but instead [sesquilinear](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesquilinear_form): it's linear in the first argument, but conjugate-linear in the second. If you're collecting examples; I can't shed any light on the general theory, unfortunately.

Comment: I am sorry, i wrote question wrong. But thanks for your link, they are really good for me.

Comment: If you are currently at UCD, you can ask Gary McGuire. He knows this stuff. Say "Hi" from me as well :-)

Comment: He is my advisor, i will say :) I am not sure they are dependent or not, but i am trying to count number of points on a curve. I am just trying to find some way.

Comment: Ok. Getting warmer. Counting points on a curve. That gives us many, many other tools. Which curve are we talking about?

Comment: Similar in the example. But higher genus.. Since it is not my research, i am trying to careful about asking "open" questions. But i really tried nearly all ways which are used. I am trying to find a different method.

Comment: i said your 'hi', he had been happy.